# jsPDF setLineWidth not working as expected

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, jspdf

All,

I have created a jsPDF function that contains of several lines between the text.
For some unknown reason the first line of the document is not the width that I set it to. Although I set the command for it:

```
doc.setLineWidth(0,5);
```

Is there a reason why the command doesn't work on the first line but does on all the next lines?

```
doc.setLineWidth(0,5);
doc.line(20, varHeight += 5, 200, varHeight) // horizontal line
```

Second problem I have is the placement of the lines. I have some blocks of text which are separated by a dividing line. I want to check if we are at the bottom of the page every time I draw a line. If we are at the bottom we don't need the line.

```
var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
function draw_the_line(h,j){
if (h <= pageHeight - 150)
   {
    doc.line(20, j, 200, j);
   } 
};
```

The code doesn't work. The line will be drawn even at the end of the page.

Tnx in advance.

Marco

Comment: Can you update your scenario in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bu9db10d/282/

Comment: So when I add the `doc.setLineWidth(0,5);` at the top of the page just after `var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4')` it only works on the first page. After a PageAdd the setting is gone.

Comment: You should use 0.5 instead of 0,5 (use the correct decimal point.)